# Making Sharepoint 2016 into Metro tiles styling similar to One Drive

Tags: style-library, style.css, onedrive, tiles

Hi why does Sharepoint 2016 look so different from Microsoft's OneDrive? is it possible to design a regular Sharepoint 2016 to have a modern metro tiles styling, like how Microsoft One Drive style?
example:
Document library to look like One Drive's Large icon views instead of a list
Employees Directory to look like One Drive's People
Calendar to look like One Drive's Calendar

Can anyone provide a step by step guide on how to make it like OneDrive?

Comment: Take the CSS from  OneDrive and apply it to the HTML a MasterPage spits out. Rule by Rule, By hand.. so it will take you a week or so.